# Error message invalid type (list) using ggadjustedcurves (survminer package) in R

Tags: r, survminer

I am trying to get a survival curve showing the effect of the variable "gender", correcting for the variable "days_to_birth".

```
fit<-coxph(Surv(time = data$futime, event = data$fustat) ~ data$gender + data$days_to_birth ,data = data)
ggadjustedcurves(fit,data=data)
```

I get the following error message: following the ggadjustedcurves function:

> invalid type (list) for variable 'data'

Yet, "data" is a data.frame:

> 'data.frame':  408 obs. of  56531 variables:
>
> $ ID  : Factor w/ 408 levels "A0C8","A0EZ",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
>
> $ fustat: int  0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 ...
>
> $ futime: int  1219 273 59 89 700 62 200 393 149 460 ...
>
> $ days_to_birth : int  -26819 -25202 -22068 -26178 -29951...
>
> $ gender: Factor w/ 2 levels "FEMALE","MALE": 2 1 2 2 1

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Try `data$surv <- Surv(time = data$futime, event = data$fustat)` then `fit<-coxph(surv ~ gender + days_to_birth ,data = data)`. You shouldn't put `data$...` in your formula

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!